# How to overlay images one on another in xsl-fo?

Tags: xsl-fo

We have 3 to 4 images in my xml,I need to place them in the pdf as it will produce on applying  xsl-fo on the xml.

We have tried with absolute positioning & all other attributes to place it over another,  but couldn't do so.
Where these images are in the mid of a page & both side of the pages contain fo:blocks with other content.

I am trying with something like this:---

```
<fo:block>
                <xsl:for-each select="topic//fig">
                            <xsl:variable name="counter">
                                <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                            </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:if test="./image/@href">

                    <xsl:if test="($counter='1')">
                            <fo:block>
                            <fo:external-graphic src="url({concat($imagesUrl-pdf,$ancestorId,'/','image/',.//image/@href)})" xsl:use-attribute-sets="image1"/>
                            </fo:block>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="($counter='2')">

                            <fo:external-graphic src="url({concat($imagesUrl-pdf,$ancestorId,'/','image/',.//image/@href)})" xsl:use-attribute-sets="image2"/>

                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="($counter='3')">
                        <fo:external-graphic src="url({concat($imagesUrl-pdf,$ancestorId,'/','image/',.//image/@href)})" xsl:use-attribute-sets="image3"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="($counter='4')">
                            <fo:block>  
                                <fo:external-graphic src="url({concat($imagesUrl-pdf,$ancestorId,'/','image/',.//image/@href)})" xsl:use-attribute-sets="image4"/>
                                </fo:block> 
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="($counter='5')">
                    <fo:block>
                            <fo:external-graphic src="url({concat($imagesUrl-pdf,$ancestorId,'/','image/',.//image/@href)})" xsl:use-attribute-sets="image5"/>
                            </fo:block> 
                    </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:if>

                </xsl:for-each> 
                    </fo:block>
```

Do suggest if this can be achieved in any way.Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Show some code and pictures of what you are trying to accomplish, it is not possible to guess at your description.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience,but i can't able to upload image as short on reputation.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of <fo:block you should use <fo:block-container position="absolute" ... and set attributes top, left, bottom, right for each image. [Fixed Position Output](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect3/fofixedposn.html)

Comment: Thanks @Alexander .It solved my issue, but could not position it to the right with the right attribute.Eventually i had to use attributes on the <fo:external-graphics> separately.